# How to disable the browser's back, forward and refresh buttons?

Tags: browser

I want to disable the browser's navigation buttons: back, forward and refresh. This is for students taking a quiz using with jQuery.

I have tried the following code but it's not working:

```
window.history.forward();
function preventBack() { window.history.forward(1); }
  function disableBackButton() {
  window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote please ? Consider to read this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @GilleQ. please check question again  i replace code there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. This will allow site-owners to hijack user's browsers. Imagine if you're stuck on a page you can't leave. If the user wants to leave, refresh or close the tab, the browser must allow this behaviour.

That being said, you can do something like

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    $.ajax('/mark-the-user-as-failed') // you may not get the response
    return 'You are not allowed to leave or refresh the page. This attempt has been logged.'
})
```

However this will also be triggered on form submits - aka legitimate requests - so you'll need to handle those cases, either by removing the handler or using a semaphore variable.

Answer (score 0):

on `document.ready` use this line..

```
window.history.forward(-1)
```

Hope it works